Maximizing Edges in Graphs Containing Specific Complete Subgraphs
I’m working on my bachelor’s thesis, which involves exploring edge maximization in graphs with certain constraints. I would appreciate some insights into the following scenarios:
For a graph ( G ) with ( n ) vertices that contains exactly one ( K_{r+1} ) subgraph, what is the maximum number of edges it can have?
If ( G ) contains exactly one ( K_{3} ) (triangle), what would be the maximum number of edges?
Lastly, if ( G ) contains exactly two ( K_{3} ) subgraphs, how does this affect the maximum number of edges?
I understand that Turán’s theorem provides a formula for the maximum number of edges in a ( K_{r+1} )-free graph, and Mantel’s theorem offers insight for the case when ( r = 2 ). However, I’m particularly interested in the adjustments needed to these formulas when the graph contains one or two complete subgraphs as specified.
Any guidance or references to relevant literature would be greatly appreciated!

Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., basic help on mathjax notation, mathjax tutorial and quick reference, main meta site math tutorial and equation editing how-to.

Suppose that $G$ contains only one copy of $K_3$ induced by $K=\{a,b,c\}$ and has maximum number of edges.  The following graph gives a lower bound $e(G)\ge ex(n-1,K_3)+2$.

Let's consider the  upper bound of $e(G)$. Since there is only one triangle $abc$ in $G$, we have $N_{V(G)-K}(a),N_{V(G)-K}(b),N_{V(G)-K}(c)$ are pairwise disjoint. So the number of edges between $K$ and $V(G)-K$ is $e(K,V(G)-K)= d(a)+d(b)+d(c)-6\le n-3$. Note that $G-K$ is $K_3$-free, so we have $e(G)\le ex(n-3,K_3)+n-3+3=ex(n-1,K_3)+2 $.
Combine the lower and upper bound, we have $e(G)=ex(n-1,K_3)+2$.
I think the other two questions is easy to handle along the above method by replacing $K_3$ with $K_{r+1}$, one $K_3$ to two $K_3$. Ask me if you have problems.
